# What is best way to compress file and text "inside browser" before sending to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, compression

Actually I trying to upload large text and pdf files. I want to compress file chunks in browser only. So i can encrypt and send these lite chunk through ajax smoothly without hanging browser. I am seeking help related to file chunk compression. And at server side easily can decompress using java library. Can anyone suggest me best way to do it ?
It should be in client side and inside browser(IE11,Google Chrome).

Comment: why is here `java` tag?

Comment: I think Amazon sends all its images as zip files, to save space and increase upload times, as is evident, but I'm not sure about the exact compression type - might be bzip or gzip.

Comment: If anyway we can call java utility inside javascript so.

Comment: http://danml.com/js/compression.js has deflate() and inflate() which works pretty well

Comment: @ArifBurhan okay but if you have some idea can you tell me which library i can you use my case.

Comment: yeah, the core was written in 1999, and now it's easier than ever to send binary without `btoa()` support

Comment: @dandavis okay I will try it out.

Comment: if you will `inflate()` with java, mind the UTF encoding of JS strings...

Comment: @dandavis sure I will do. One more thing , where can i get document for this library(danml.com/js/compression.js ) then it will be easy for me.

Comment: afaik, there is none. `deflate(strContent)` returns `strCompressed`, `inflate()` does the opposite. `inflate(deflate("hello"))=="hello";`

Comment: @dandavis okay , thanks

Answer (score 5):

Gzip is a popular method for compressing data before sending it over the web.

There are many javascript libraries, such as https://github.com/beatgammit/gzip-js which will compress a string/byte array for you.

Java has Gzip functionality built-in through `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;`; a simple google search will make it easy to learn how to use it.

Comment: thanks but I have to use in production so i have some restrictions on GPL license so. If you can help me with client side with other library please.  I m okay with server side GZIP.

Answer (score 0):

There are several JS libs that can help you with that, if the `zip` format is acceptable. [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) is one of the most well known ones.

Comment: thanks but It's under gpl so I can't use it. If any other suggestions please let me know.